# option to automatically create storage account missing

Tags: azure

When i deploy an arm template via visual studio I used to have an option to automatically create a storage account when deploying a template but now the option has gone!? Can anyone advise why it would have disappeared and how to get it back

Comment: Could you show the template here so that we can test it for troubleshooting?

Comment: its any project, if i start a brand new one and just add a vnet and vm, i used to get an option to automatically create a storage account and now that option is no longer visible in the drop down box

Comment: Did you try to depoly your template in Cutom deployment via Azure Portal ?

Comment: i can try that , i have done that

Comment: i need to be able to deploy from visual studio. There used to be the option to automatically create a storage account and now its disappeared?